# Polyline on a google map not showing in a Tabbed Activity in Android App

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

My Android app has 4 tabs in which one tab is having map fragment with a polyline on map,It should display a line from location A to Location B.In a normal activity it is showing the polyline but in the tabbed activity it is not showing.

Here is my Tab2.Activity

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Tab2 extends SupportMapFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

private GoogleMap googleMap;
Polyline line;
Context context;

LatLng startLatLng = new LatLng(17.4487775,78.3480138);
LatLng endLatLng = new LatLng(17.484722, 77.971126);

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_2, null, false);
    context = getActivity();
    initilizeMap();
    return v;
}

private void initilizeMap() {
    SupportMapFragment mSupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (mSupportMapFragment == null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mSupportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.map, mSupportMapFragment).commit();
    }
    if (mSupportMapFragment != null) {
        mSupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                if (googleMap != null) {

                    googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(startLatLng).zoom(15.0f).build();
                    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
                    googleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
                    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                    //googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(17.396678, 78.3103592))
                            .title("Support Station - 1"));

                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(17.418662, 78.222020))
                            .title("Support Station - 2"));

                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(17.460509, 78.107087))
                            .title("Support Station - 3"));

                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(17.467745, 78.033966))
                            .title("Support Station - 4"));

                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(17.484722, 77.971126))
                            .title("Support Station - 5"));

                    String urlTopass = makeURL(startLatLng.latitude,
                            startLatLng.longitude, endLatLng.latitude,
                            endLatLng.longitude);
                    new connectAsyncTask(urlTopass).execute();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}

private class connectAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String url;

    connectAsyncTask(String urlPass) {
        url = urlPass;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching route, Please wait...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.hide();
        if (result != null) {
            drawPath(result);
        }
    }
}

public String makeURL(double sourcelat, double sourcelog, double destlat,
                      double destlog) {
    StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
    urlString.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
    urlString.append("?origin=");// from
    urlString.append(Double.toString(sourcelat));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append(Double.toString(sourcelog));
    urlString.append("&destination=");// to
    urlString.append(Double.toString(destlat));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append(Double.toString(destlog));
    urlString.append("&sensor=false&mode=driving&alternatives=true");
    return urlString.toString();
}

public class JSONParser {

    InputStream is = null;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {
    }

    public String getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            json = sb.toString();
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        return json;

    }
}

public void drawPath(String result) {
    if (line != null) {
        googleMap.clear();
    }
    try {
        // Tranform the string into a json object
        final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
        JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes
                .getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
        String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(encodedString);

        for (int z = 0; z < list.size() - 1; z++) {
            LatLng src = list.get(z);
            LatLng dest = list.get(z + 1);
            line = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                    .add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),
                            new LatLng(dest.latitude, dest.longitude))
                    .width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
}
```

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

// Declaring Your View and Variables

Toolbar toolbar;
ViewPager pager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
SlidingTabLayout tabs;
CharSequence Titles[]={"Event Flow","Route","Support Stations","Contact Us"};
int Numboftabs =4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });

    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);


}
```

}